# How do i convert (pulled from device) individual frames to a video file on linux and push it back to the same directory

Tags: android, ffmpeg, terminal, ubuntu-11.04, android-sdcard

First of all i have frames on my SD Card and frames are there in separate folders for each video..

what i want to do is that i just want to make REALLY simple Java application for user(just a button to make video files) on the linux OS whose ActionEvent Handler pulls in all the individual frames and converts it to a video..deletes all the frames from the SD Card and then pushes the video file back to the same directory of SD Card..

i wanted to know how do i pack frames into a video file on Linux(Ubuntu)..i think there is something ffmpeg but i dont know much..
Can someone provide a example..please .. the images are named as image0000  to image9999

and is it possible to create video file from those frames AND EVEN having sound in them using ffmpeg..?

Can adb pull and push files without SD Card being connected..

And finally wanted to know how do i run shell commands like adb pull, push, ffmpeg from JAVA..

THERE ARE i think 4 QUESTIONS here but all related so i thought better ask them together..Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a OS call from Java like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandString);
```

Here is how to convert a set of images to a video:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%04d.jpg video.mpg
```

And here how you can add sound to this video:

```
ffmpeg -i sound.mp3 -i video_in.avi video_out.avi
```

Comment: I know replying verry late .. but Thanks! :) i did refer and made an Android App!